# The motion of the car in a straight way

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I was reading a PDF about [Optimal Time Car Control](https://wwwproxy.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/~Huu.Chuong.La/practicality/mstime.pdf) and I have doubt about the formulation of Newton's second law that is proposed (See the image)
[image]

I do not understand why you get $\ddot{x}(t)=-kx(t)+w(t)$ , I have made the respective free body diagram but I still can not find the expression $-kx(t)$.

Could you help me?

Comment: Coefficient of friction is not normally multiplied by position, rather a force compresing twosurfaces. So it looks very odd, either an error or there is some contextual information about the set up that is in the book but not providd here.

Comment: Typo?  Could it be $- k x^\prime (t)$ ?  Then you've got friction slowing things down and presumably the work of the engine giving $w(t)$.

Comment: What is this sourced from? It's got a lot of odd language in it, like referring to the variable $x(t)$ as "the state."

Comment: @probably_someone https://wwwproxy.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/~Huu.Chuong.La/practicality/mstime.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about control theory, but its clear that almost everything in [this paper](https://wwwproxy.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/~Huu.Chuong.La/practicality/mstime.pdf) is complete nonsense. The equation you've reproduced is exactly that of an [undamped driven harmonic oscillator](http://www.cts.iitkgp.ac.in/home/pratik/forcednew.pdf), where $w(t)$ behaves as a forcing function. You might use this equation if your car was being dangled by a spring in the hand of a giant monster, and $w(t)$ is the height of the monster's hand at time $t$.
While there is some ambiguity in the phrase "a car driving on the straight way", the situation just described would certainly be stretching things.

The other equations in the article also don't make any sense. For example, the "ODE" presented reduces to the trivial relationship:
$$x(t) = y(t) = \frac{1}{2} w(t)$$
Which is not an ODE at all, and has no relation to the harmonic oscillator.

How did you come across this article? I would steer clear (pardon the pun) of other work from the same source; there's plenty of legitimate references on control theory that would come up with a quick google search.

Answer (score 0):

I looked closer at the paper you cite. Yes, it's a typo in the equation you show here. It should be $-k x^\prime(t)$. The next group of equations has substituted $y(t) = x^\prime (t)$ and made yet more typos.  They should have this.

$$ y^\prime (t) = - k\ y(t) +w(t)$$

But they have dropped the prime on the $y$ on the left, and the $k$ on the right.

For the special case of $w(t)=a$ where $a$ is constant, which they eventually begin to consider, this equation can be solved in closed form. If I've remembered my calculus correctly it gives this.

$$ y(t) = \frac{a}{K} \left( 1 - e^{-kt}  \right) $$

And yet they talk about needing to do it numerically.

The thing is, they seem to be interested in optimization rather than the motion of the car. What $w(t)$ will minimize the time to a given distance, with constraints on $w$, and such that the car stops at the given distance? That's the real problem they want to solve. They certainly have not explained it very well on that page. It could actually be an interesting problem behind all the typos.

Comment: Even the expression $-kx'(t)$ doesn't describe friction; rather, it describes drag.

Comment: @probably_someone  Drag is more typically proportional to the square of speed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)  This is because at double the speed it hits twice as much mass twice as hard.  Probably the linear term was chosen to be easy to solve rather than for being especially a good model of any real situation.

Comment: Linear drag definitely exists. Stokes drag, which is linear in speed, applies in the laminar flow regime at very low speeds or very high viscosities (in general, at small Reynolds number).

Answer (score 0):

The intended formulation of the car point-mass dynamics should read $\ddot{x}(t) = -c_0 - c_v \dot{x}(t) - c_a \dot{x}^2(t) + w(t)$ where the states of the dynamical system are $x$ and $\dot{x}$ with $0 < c_0, c_v, c_a$ being the *Davis coefficients* obtained from wind-tunnel experiments. This model is commonly used in motion planning and control of autonomous trains. See https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8640848 for more details.